# Divide the string into parts and convert it to an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

It is necessary to split the string every 500 symbols, and put every part into array.

Example:

```
$str = "xx...xxxx" (1550 symbols)
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(500) "xxx.xx"
  [1]=>
  string(500) "xxx.xx"
  [2]=>
  string(500) "xxx.xx"
  [3]=>
  string(50) "xxx.xx"
}
```

Tried this way, but this is not what I need:

```
$arr = str_split($str,500);
```

How to solve this problem in the best way?

Thnx!

Comment: What's wrong with the result of `str_split`?

Comment: the code you posted should result in something almost exactly like the Result you showed us. Example (using 5 instead of 500, for the sake of brevity): https://eval.in/1032913 So...what do you want instead? You say it's not what you need, but then don't make clear what specifically you _do_ need?

Comment: I suppose OP's string is in UTF or other multibyte.

Comment: Although OP doesn't help with his lack of information in his question i think that maybe he is dealing with a multi-byte encoded string and thus it is not spliting it as it should because "str_split() will split into bytes, rather than characters when dealing with a multi-byte encoded string."

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for me

```
function split($str, $len = 1) {
    $arr    = [];
    $length   = mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i += $len) {
        $arr[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $len, 'UTF-8');
    }
    return $arr;
}
$arr = split($cart,55);
```

u_mulder, thanx for the hint with UTF encoding:)